# update sqlite db row when opened from listview in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a listview  from an sqlite db and when i click it, it opens up the corresponding text, I want to add it to a favourites folder by clicking a button which updates a column in the row to "y". Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the update query

```
pssQliteHelper = PSSQliteHelper.getInstance(context); 
SQLiteDatabase db = pssQliteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("y", true);  
db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues,  " id = '" + dbInsertionId + "'",null); 
db.close();
```